# How do I get a follower back after telling them to wait?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In *Skyrim* on Xbox 360, I told my follower (a dark brotherhood initiate) to wait at the foot of the staircase in Folgunthur during the quest to get the fragment, and when I came back to get her, she was nowhere to be found. I've even waited for three days and haven't gotten a message that she got tired of waiting and returned home. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: try looking at your home? They might have gone back. Look around where you told them to wait, they may move a bit, maybe even died

Comment: Check the answer to the duplicate @TrentHawkins suggests. While your question is slightly different, I would expect the answer to be the same.